# Open tab in existing connection of filezilla with command line

Tags: 16.04

Is there a way to open a new tab in an existing connection of FileZilla using command line?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is **no.**

Source:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/filezilla